# start and end date of a weeks in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want the required start and end date of a week in the following format by using  php.

Range: `16-Jan-2018 to 22-Jan-2018`

I have got the start date and end dates. I just don't know how to put start date and end date of multiple weeks in array against one index. As in

```
Range[0] = 16-Jan-2018, 22-Jan-2018

Range[1] = 22-Jan-2018,27-Jan-2018
```

Comment: try with this : `echo str_replace(',', ' to ', '16-Jan-2018, 22-Jan-2018');`

Comment: see this ;https://eval.in/1018239

Answer (score 0):

use `str_replace` to get the desired result

```
$range[0] = '16-Jan-2018, 22-Jan-2018';

echo str_replace(',', ' to ', $range[0]);
```

*Output*

```
'16-Jan-2018 to 22-Jan-2018'
```

*With `$range` using loop see* : https://eval.in/1018286